# What do blank regions in the waf parallel_debug image indicate?

Tags: waf

We use the `waf` build system. I'm trying to improve throughput/build time, especially when no changes were made. I have found the image generated by the `parallel_debug` plugin helpful (https://gitlab.com/search?search=parallel_debug&nav_source=navbar&project_id=7131569&search_code=true&repository_ref=master)

However! I see "blank areas" in my pdebug.svg image:
[image: waf profile showing a blank area between two targets]

This is the profile from a "no changes" build. It took about 30s, 6 of which were a mystery. I'm interested in the blank area in the top row - **what was `waf` doing during this time?** Or does anyone have advice for what I could do to figure out what waf was doing?

Comment: Well, you can use the extra verbose flags (-vvv) to have a clue